# How To fix System.TypeInitializationException in this code

Tags: c#, xml, carrot2

I have a problem with some code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Org.Carrot2.Core;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Examples.NET
{
internal static class SampleDocumentData
{
    public static readonly IList<Document> DataMiningDocuments = new List<Document>();
    static SampleDocumentData()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("hadits.xml");
        Console.Write("Masukan kata kunci pencarian: ");
        string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

        //Navigate through all IsiNode
        foreach (var isiElement in doc.Root.Elements())
        {
            if (isiElement.Value.Contains(keyword))
            {
                string[] xdata={isiElement.Value};
                for (int i = 0; i < xdata.Length; i++)
                {
                    DataMiningDocuments.Add(new Document(xdata[i], xdata[i], ""));
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        
    }
}
```

}

It is producing the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException
>
> The type initializer for 'Examples.NET.SampleDocumentData' threw an exception.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: An uncaught exception occurs in this static constructor. Catch it and handle it or ensure it cannot occur. You appear to be doing far to much in a static constructor. You likely should make this a class that takes the name of the document to load as its constructor argument.

Comment: Also, doing a `Console.ReadLine()` in a static constructor? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Any exception occurred in static constructor will be wrapped by TypeInitializationException. So just fix throwing exception in your static constructor and TypeInitializationException will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The question you asked is not correct. The correct question is: why is the static block throwing the exception (when it shouldn't)?

You're modifying an example from Carrot2 that had a set of static example documents. Move the entire block reading those documents to your normal code (not class initializer) and use it there. If it throws an exception (which isn't going to propagate wrapped as class init exception), provide the full exception's stack trace and message -- this will give you a clue why the code is not working as expected.